# Symmetric Matrix in SO(3) : Exponential Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, rotations, orthogonality

Let $R\in $ SO(3), that is $R$ is real $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix with determinant $+1$. I am trying prove that if $R= R^\top$, and $R\in $ SO(3) then $R \in \{exp(k\pi \hat{a}) | k\in \mathbb{Z}, a \in S^2  \}$.

Attempt so far : 
I realize that $R$ will have the following form, $R=QDQ^\top$ where $Q,D\in$ SO(3), and $D$ is diagonal. That is 
$D\in \{ diag([1\; 1 \;1]), diag([-1 \;-1\; 1]), diag([-1 \; 1 \;-1]), diag([1 \;-1\; -1]) \}$

However, I am unable to see how exponential map comes into the picture.

EDIT : I found another question similar to mine here. One of the answers uses an exponential formula, understanding that probably would help me to prove this.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/835858/153354

Comment: We can see that up to conjugacy by elements of $SO(3)$, there are only two forms of elements in $D$, namely, $I$ and $\operatorname{diag}(-1, -1, 1)$. Geometrically these respectively fix everything and reflect through the $z$-axis.

Comment: Thanks, Travis. I am unable to see how exponential expression can be used. I found another question similar to mine here - 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835829/what-can-be-said-about-a-matrix-which-is-both-symmetric-and-orthogonal

One of the answers uses an exponential formula, understanding that probably would help me to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that changing the roation Matrix into a form of a unitary Operator might help.

Starting that an infinitesimal rotation will be the same as a unitary operator, taylor expand both.

A rotation aroundan axis, represented by unit vector a, and an angle $\theta$

$ R( \theta ) = 1 + \frac{\partial R(\theta)}{\partial ( \theta)} \theta  \hat{n} + .... $

and a Unitary operator is

$ U(\theta) = 1 + \frac{\partial U(\theta)}{\partial \theta} \theta \hat{n} + ...$

Then, if we introduce a factor k,

$$ \frac{\partial R(\theta)}{\partial \theta}  = k \frac{\partial U(\theta)}{\partial \theta} $$

And as any unitary operator can be representated as an exponential,

$$R( \theta) = U(\theta) = e^{{k}{a}\hat{n}}$$

A proof of a rotation having to be around an axis is an assumption and is not proved here.